# How to use images for charts in Highcharts

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts

Is this kind of thing possible with Highcharts?
[image]

I have been doing some charts using PowerBI and created a chart like above to represent Male/Female distribution of a company. But now I need to do that using Highcharts. Is it possible to the same using Highharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering you question. Yes, it is possible to achieve what you are trying to do.

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21993#p86158

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42209